# Listar array de acordo com o que foi selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `select`com algumas operadoras de celular:

```
<select name="valor" id="operadoraRecarga" class="form-control operadoraRecarga">
<option value="claro">Claro</option>
<option value="tim">Tim</option>
<option value="oi">Oi</option>
<option value="vivo">Vivo</option>
<option value="nextel">Nextel</option>
</select>
```

E tenho um lista de array com os valores de recarga de cada operadora

```
var claro_array  = new Array('10.00', '13.00', '15.00', '20.00', '30.00', '50.00', '100.00');
      var vivo_array   = new Array('5.00', '10.00', '15.00', '20.00', '25.00', '35.00', '100.00');
      var oi_array     = new Array('10.00', '14.00', '18.00', '20.00', '25.00', '30.00', '35.00', '40.00', '50.00', '75.00', '100.00');
      var tim_array    = new Array('7.00', '15.00', '20.00', '30.00', '35.00', '50.00', '100.00');
      var nextel_array = new Array('20.00', '30.00', '50.00', '100.00');
```

Eu tenho o código abaixo aonde de acordo com o que foi selecionado no `select` ele já seleciona o array certo para montar o outro `select`de valores, mas o problema é que ao inves de ele fazer isso ele está pegando cada letra da palavra (ex: tim_array) e montando o select, ficando cada option tipo assim:

```
Option 1: t
Option 2: i
Option 3: m
```

**Meu Código**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      var claro_array  = new Array('10.00', '13.00', '15.00', '20.00', '30.00', '50.00', '100.00');
      var vivo_array   = new Array('5.00', '10.00', '15.00', '20.00', '25.00', '35.00', '100.00');
      var oi_array     = new Array('10.00', '14.00', '18.00', '20.00', '25.00', '30.00', '35.00', '40.00', '50.00', '75.00', '100.00');
      var tim_array    = new Array('7.00', '15.00', '20.00', '30.00', '35.00', '50.00', '100.00');
      var nextel_array = new Array('20.00', '30.00', '50.00', '100.00');

      $("#operadoraRecarga").change(function(){

        var selecionado = $("#operadoraRecarga option:selected").val();
        var nome_array = selecionado+'_array';
        var html = '';

        $("#valorRecarga").find('option').remove();

        for(i = 0; i <= nome_array.length; i++){

          html += '<option value="'+nome_array[i]+'">'+nome_array[i]+'</option>';

          }

        $("#valorRecarga").append(html);
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possivel ir buscar o valor de uma variável criando uma string com o seu nome...

Ou seja:

```
var exemplo = 10;
alert('exe' + 'mplo');
```

não vai dar 10, mas sim uma string, com as letras "exemplo".

Mas podes usar essa lógica se criares um objeto e acederes às suas propriedades da maneira que referimos em cima, com colchetes. Nesse caso seria o exemplo assim:

```
var obj = {exemplo: 10};
alert(obj['exe' + 'mplo']);
```

e aí sim já daria `10`!

No código deverias então ter assim:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var precos = {
        claro: ["10.00", "13.00", "15.00", "20.00", "30.00", "50.00", "100.00"],
        vivo: ["5.00", "10.00", "15.00", "20.00", "25.00", "35.00", "100.00"],
        oi: ["10.00", "14.00", "18.00", "20.00", "25.00", "30.00", "35.00", "40.00", "50.00", "75.00", "100.00"],
        tim: ["7.00", "15.00", "20.00", "30.00", "35.00", "50.00", "100.00"],
        nextel: ["20.00", "30.00", "50.00", "100.00"]
    }

    $("#operadoraRecarga").change(function() {
        var selecionado = this.value;
        var html = precos[selecionado].reduce(function(str, preco) {
            return str + '<option value="' + preco + '">' + preco + '</option>';
        }, '');
        $("#valorRecarga").html(html);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="valor" id="operadoraRecarga" class="form-control operadoraRecarga">
    <option value="claro">Claro</option>
    <option value="tim">Tim</option>
    <option value="oi">Oi</option>
    <option value="vivo">Vivo</option>
    <option value="nextel">Nextel</option>
</select>
<select id="valorRecarga"></select>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmg4fyqq/

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente há alguns problemas no código

```
for(i = 0; i <= nome_array.length; i++){
```

Isso vai fazer com que o loop execute +1 vez do que esperado, pois (supondo que `nome_array.length` fosse `10`: `10 <= 10` --> `true`, `0 <= 10;` --> o loop seria executado 11 vezes. E você está deixando o `i` global, o que pode causar alguns problemas no futuro.

Segundo,

```
var nome_array = selecionado+'_array';
```

, isso resulta em uma `String`, por exemplo (dependendo de `selecionado`):

```
"claro_array"
```

Por causa disso o loop só leu os caracteres dessa string, desde que cada caractere pode ser identificado com as chaves `[..]`, `String().charAt` e `String().charCodeAt`.

Uma ótima coisa que você pode fazer é colocar todas essas arrays `claro_array`, `tim_array`, etc, em um objeto, então indexá-lo com `selecionado`.

```
var arrays  = {
    claro: ['10.00', '13.00', '15.00', '20.00', '30.00', '50.00', '100.00'],
    vivo: ['5.00', '10.00', '15.00', '20.00', '25.00', '35.00', '100.00'],
    oi: ['10.00', '14.00', '18.00', '20.00', '25.00', '30.00', '35.00', '40.00', '50.00', '75.00', '100.00'],
    tim: ['7.00', '15.00', '20.00', '30.00', '35.00', '50.00', '100.00'],
    nextel: ['20.00', '30.00', '50.00', '100.00']
};

var nome_array = arrays[selecionado];

/**
 * Fashion com o for... of
 */
for (var item of nome_array)
    html += '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var claro_array  = new Array('10.00', '13.00', '15.00', '20.00', '30.00', '50.00', '100.00');
$('#select').empty();
$.each(options, function(i, p) {
    $('#select').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
});
```

Onde '#select' é o elemento que você quer exibir o array!